# How to run a batch file localy from windows ssh server (from linux machine on remote windows machine)

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, command-prompt, remote-server

I trying to run a following batch file:

```
echo on
title My Batch File
:: See title 
call myApplication.exe
echo I am done
pause
```

I tried two different scenarios:
If I want to launch an application with GUI it tells me that I don't have enough space

```
Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

If I want to do something very light, a program as simple as printing something on command prompt, it will do the work.

My real difficulty: I need to launch a cmd on the remote machine not in my ssh terminal. The reason is I need to access the usb-drive on the local windows machine, but this situation I cannot really do it.
What I really need to do: open command prompt remotely on a windows machine
Thank you

My setup:

host PC : Debian Linux
Remote PC: Windows 10 running ssh server (default to Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

What ssh server are you using? Try cygwin or likes because windows doesnt have built in ssh servers. It does have a telnet client. If security is not an issue and the linux server is running locally, you can try doing that.

Comment: Make sure you dont have firewall issues.

Comment: Windows 10 comes with its own native ssh server. I have no problem connecting to the server. Everything seems okay. I just don't know how to launch something as simple as cmd on the remote computer. I believe there should be a env variable to do that, but I cannot find anything.

Comment: All the firewalls and securities are completely out of the way and disabled